# package incompatibility: csvsimple & etextools

Tags: incompatibility, csvsimple, etextools

The following code fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{etextools}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \csvloop already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.920 \DeclareCmdListParser\csvloop{,}
```

What is the appropriate way to solve this? The only way I can currently think of is to call `\def\csvloop\@undefined` in between loading the packages, but this seems a little radical to me.

Is this incompatibility known? Is one of the packages deprecated and/or can be replaced by something else that provides similar capabilities but does not exhibit this behavior?

Comment: The `etextools` package is buggy and its author abandoned it.

Comment: What do you use `etextools` for?

Comment: Mostly `\iftoggle`, `\newtoggle`, `\toggletrue`, `\togglefalse` etc.

Comment: Those are in `etoolbox`, no need of `etextools` for them.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of that. Swapping `etextools` for `etoolbox` works for me, so that solves it, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need some of the commands in `etextools`, you may load the package `scrlfile` from the [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script) bundle. This package controls the loading of packages, classes and files and their behaviour. It also has functions in a safe way to save macros to helper macros, and restore them after loading problematic packages. You may then:

1. Load `csvsimple`
2. Save the csvsimple-macro `csvloop`
3. Load the `etextools`packages
4. In a controlled manner restore the `csvloop` from `csvsimple`

Have a look at page 263 and onwards in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), where the different commands are described in detail with examples of their use.