# I can't use a saved dimension in an anchor into a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I have the following problem: Into a `\pgfdeclareshape` I have the following code for a saved dimension:

```
\saveddimen{\long@sal}{
  \pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/longitud salidas}\unidad@medicion
  \advance\pgf@x\y@colect
}
```

Then, when I try to use in:

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,7}{
  \xdef\doanchor{
    \noexpand\anchor{o\n}{
      \@tempdima=2\x@colect % \sep@sal
      \divide\@tempdima\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/salidas}
      \noexpand\pgfpoint{
        -\x@colect + 0.5\@tempdima + (\n-1)*\@tempdima
      }{\long@sal}
    }
  }
  \doanchor
}
```

I get the error: `! Undefined control sequence.`

The problem is due to `\long@sal`, I'm sure. Please, someone can help me?

Comment: Every loop cycle of `\foreach` is executed in a group, so nothing local is persistent between iterations. You have different choices, for example: define things globally, or use a loop from another package.

Comment: In addition to what @Kpym is saying you could smuggle the macro out of the group: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799

Comment: @Kpym I also used `\loop \repeat` tex and it doesn't work. Defining globaly `\long@sal` neither works because its value can't be modified into `\pgfdeclareshape`.

Comment: @marmot Thanks. I'm afraid that the referred code is so tricky for me than I'll be more than a while to digest it. What's more, I think that I am not be able to understand it.

Comment: @marmot and @Kpym I found the solution. It was easier than it seemed: the problem was solved adding `\newdimen\long@sal` before `\pfgdeclareshape`.

Comment: You can answer now your own question (and accept it). This is a good practice (for different reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, the solution is easy. Including `\newdimen\long@sal` before `\pfgdeclareshape`, and it properly works.