# Best practice for printing and evaluating formulas with the minimal coding

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, pgfmath

Can the following MWE be reduced by creating a command that can accept a formula then print and evaluate it without the need to write it twice in two different forms for both evaluating and printing as shown below?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,mathtools,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\toprint}{\frac{-4+\sqrt{4^2-4*1*3}}{2}}
\newcommand{\toevaluate}{(-4+sqrt(4^2-4*1*3))/2}

\pgfmathparse{\toevaluate}

The first root is evaluated by $x_1 = \toprint =  \SI{\pgfmathresult}{\cm} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such function available but I may be wrong. You *could* write your own parser that locally redefines the macros that print stuff to macros that wraps stuff in the respective functions. In the code below, I do that for `\frac` and `\sqrt`. This works in this case, also because you were kind enough to explicitly spell out multiplications and even used `*` for them. Clearly, this "parser" is fragile, but if you really feel it is worthwhile you may add other functions like `\sin` and so on.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,mathtools,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\toprint}{\frac{-4+\sqrt{4^2-4*1*3}}{2}}
%\newcommand{\toevaluate}{(-4+sqrt(4^2-4*1*3))/2}
\newcommand{\DiaaParse}[1]{\begingroup\def\frac##1##2{((##1)/(##2))}%
\def\sqrt##1{sqrt(##1)}%
\edef\ret{#1}%
\pgfmathparse{\ret}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
\endgroup}

%\pgfmathparse{\toevaluate}

The first root is evaluated by $x_1 = \toprint =  \DiaaParse{\toprint}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This version does not work with `\SI`, also because I didn't understand where the units `cm` come from, but this could be changed.

If you want the parser just to parse and to store the result in `\pgfmathresult`, you could use

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,mathtools,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\toprint}{\frac{-4+\sqrt{4^2-4\times1\times 3}}{2}}
\newcommand{\DiaaParse}[1]{\begingroup\def\frac##1##2{((##1)/(##2))}%
\def\sqrt##1{sqrt(##1)}%
\def\cdot{*}%
\def\times{*}%
\def\exp##1{exp(##1)}%
\def\log##1{log(##1)}%
\def\ln##1{ln(##1)}%
\def\arcsin##1{asin(##1)}%
\def\cot##1{cot(##1)}%
\def\sin##1{sin(##1)}%
\def\sinh##1{sinh(##1)}%
\def\arccos##1{acos(##1)}%
\def\cot##1{cot(##1)}%
\def\cos##1{cos(##1)}%
\def\arctan##1{atan(##1)}%
\def\cot##1{cot(##1)}%
\def\tan##1{tan(##1)}%
\def\tanh##1{tanh(##1)}%
\def\arccot##1{acot(##1)}%
\def\cot##1{cot(##1)}%
\def\cot##1{cot(##1)}%
\edef\ret{#1}%
\pgfmathparse{\ret}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup}


The first root is evaluated by $x_1 = \toprint =\DiaaParse{\toprint}
\SI{\pgfmathresult}{\cm}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, this does work with `\SI` and so on, simply because it wraps the additional parsing around `\pgfmathparse`. This also defines the replacement rules for other commands, but I stress it is fragile. Please note that this requires a rather recent version of pgf (3.1.1 or higher, I think) which has `\pgfmathsmuggle` in it. For older versions, you have to use other smuggling techniques, see the answers [of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470961/121799) for possible ways.

Overall this does something of the sort you are suggesting, but I stress it is fragile. What if a user wants to compute, say, `\log_{7} 29`? Yes, one could extend the parser to deal with that as well, but this will be more effort. And then the next user wants `\sqrt[3]{19}`. Also possible, but more efforts. And how about `\log_{10} 3\frac{1}{4}`, how would the parser know that this is `log(13/4)/log(7)`? Of course, if you use external programs, you can avoid duplication, e.g. Mathematica has TeXForm to convert the result of some module to not-so-nice but most times working (La)TeX code.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to deal with the multiplication in the form of `\times` instead of `*`?

Comment: @Diaa You just have to add `\def\cdot{*}%`, which I added in the second example.

Comment: @Diaa This works the same for times: `\def\times{*}%`.

Comment: It would be absolutely great if your answer can be extended to a package if there isn't any.

Comment: @Diaa I recommend `tikzmarmots`. It does not produce precisely the same output, but is much more entertaining. ;-) More seriously, I can see that why folks are reluctant to write such a package. It will be (almost) inevitably fragile. So you spend 10 minutes on writing the core functions and 5 month on making it more robust. It is almost trivial to add the functions of section **94.3 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions** of the pgfmanual 3.1.3 to the above parser but very hard to cope with all the ways users may typeset their expressions.

Comment: The robustness is the main issue here. However, I believe that someday a hero will show up to make this package :)

Comment: @Diaa If I would have to guess, then I'd think that the author/maintainer of `siunitx` will have the best chances of accomplishing this. `siunitx` does already a lot of related things and its maintainer presumably has a very good idea of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Some years ago, I had the same problem.

Since writing a robust parser is not a trivial exercise, I decided to not try it in TeX, but use Python (version 3.6 or later) instead.

The result was the [TeXcalc](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/texcalc) module.

The input looks like this:

```
from texcalc import Calculation

c = Calculation()
c.add('rho_f', '1.62', 'g/cm^3', 'Fiber density')
c.add('rho_r', '1.2', 'g/cm^3', "Resin density")
c.add('v_f', '0.3', '-', 'Fiber volume fraction')
c.add('W_f', '450', 'g/m^2', "Area weight fibers", fmt=".0f")
c.add('t_f', 'W_f/(10000*rho_f)*10', 'mm')
c.add('t', 't_f/v_f', 'mm', "Laminate thickness")
c.add('t_r', 't-t_f', 'mm')
c.add('W_r', 't_f/10*(10000*rho_r)', 'g/m^2', "Area weight resin", fmt=".0f")
print(c)
```

It outputs an `align*` environment (from the `amsmath` package) and uses `siunitx` to typeset the units. After processing with LaTeX, the output looks like this.
[image: TexCalc example]

---

**Adapted to the MWE on request**

The following are the contents of `mwe.py`

```
from texcalc import Calculation

c = Calculation()
c.add('b', 4)
c.add('a', 1)
c.add('c', 3)
c.add('x1', '(-b+sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2', 'cm', 'first root')
c.add('x2', '(-b-sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2', 'cm', 'second root')
print(c)
```

Run this as `python3 mwe.py > foo.tex`

This is `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\input{foo.tex}
\end{document}
```

Run this with `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

This results in:
[image: MWE image]

The goal of TeXcalc is to clarify complicated calculations that have multiple steps, as shown in the first example. This to make it easier for others to follow.

So it cannot *exactly* match your MWE, since it doesn't produce in-line math. Although in this case, you could extract the necessary data from `foo.tex`.

Comment: Your answer looks interesting. Could you please adapt it to my MWE?

Comment: @Diaa: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As promised in the comments to my [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9fdI.png) where I use `calculator` package, I'm including, happily, my code with an articulated algorithm a bit confusing :-), which could be improved to be shorter than this MWE. But it certainly works.

---

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{calculator}


\begin{document}

\SQUARE{4}{\tempA}
\COPY{-4}{\tempB}
\COPY{4}{\tempC}
\COPY{1}{\tempD}
\COPY{3}{\tempE}
\COPY{2}{\tempG}
\MULTIPLY{\tempC}{\tempD}{\solA}
\MULTIPLY{\solA}{\tempE}{\solB}
\SUBTRACT{\tempA}{\solB}{\sol}
\SQUAREROOT{\sol}{\tempF}
\ADD{\tempB}{\tempF}{\result}
\DIVIDE{\result}{\tempG}{\divisio}
\TRUNCATE[1]{\divisio}{\division}

\begin{align*}
\frac{-4+\sqrt{4^2-4\times 1\times 3}}{2}
&= \frac{\tempB+\tempF}{\tempG}\\
&= \division \text{ cm }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It helped me.

Comment: @Diaa I'm very glady :-) and I hope that it is comprensible :-)....I'm scarce user.