# Open source tool to compute/calculate numeric latex equations?

Tags: calculations

## Scenario

Currently, when I substitute values in an equation written in latex, I copy paste that into wolfram alpha, which has difficulties handling the `\cdot` and longer equations. Which leads to unnecessary manual labor. Mathematica might be able to handle those but it is not open source.

## Question

Is there open source software that can-, or a way to automatically compute the answer of an equation?*

*without having to write the numeric equation twice (once in latex and another one in side-compiled code)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491542/2288) can help you.

Comment: OMG look at [this!](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2019/05/launching-today-free-wolfram-engine-for-developers/). Is it possible now integrate Mathematica with TeX?