# Could you tell me how to Count intersection points in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

in this picture: there are 6 intersection points. I need 6 auto change when number of intersection points change. Can you help me?
[image]

my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth]

\draw[gray!30](-3,-3) grid (3,3);

\draw[->](-3,0)--(3,0) node[below]{$x$};

\draw[->](0,-3)--(0,3) node[right]{$y$};

\draw[blue,name path=hamso] plot[domain=-2.1:2.1] (\x,{(\x)^3-3*(\x)}) 
node[right, red] {$y=x^3-3x$};

\draw[red,name path=tron] (0,0) circle(2);

\fill[violet,name intersections={of=hamso and tron,name=A,total=\t}]

\foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {(A-\i) circle (2pt) node[above]{\i}};
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]{There are: \fbox{6} intersection points};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's already available.  You're doing `total=\t`, so just write `\fbox{\t}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke `\fbox{\t}` do not work. May be `total=\t` is locally deffined only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Henri wanted to tell you that you only make `\t` global (or smuggle it out of the path). One way of accomplishing this is to add `\pgfextra{\xdef\myt{\t}}` to the path, which stores `\t` in the global macro `\myt`. (Advanced possibilities of smuggling can be found e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470961), but I think here you almost necessarily need to globalize the macro.) **EDIT**: Made this handle the case of 0 intersections, too.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth]

\draw[gray!30](-3,-3) grid (3,3);

\draw[->](-3,0)--(3,0) node[below]{$x$};

\draw[->](0,-3)--(0,3) node[right]{$y$};

\draw[blue,name path=hamso] plot[domain=-2.1:2.1] (\x,{(\x)^3-3*(\x)}) 
node[right, red] {$y=x^3-3x$};

\draw[red,name path=tron] (0,0) circle(2);

\fill[violet,name intersections={of=hamso and tron,name=A,total=\t}]
\ifnum\t>0
foreach \i in {1,...,\t} {(A-\i) circle (2pt) node[above]{\i}}
\fi
\pgfextra{\xdef\myt{\t}};
\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]{There are: \fbox{\myt} intersection points};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the cubic curve to

```
\draw[blue,name path=hamso] plot[domain=-2.1:2.1] (\x,{7+(\x)^3-3*(\x)}) 
node[right, red] {$y=7+x^3-3x$};
```

you'll get

[image]

Comment: page 145 of the manual states --  `/tikz/intersection/total=(macro)
This key means that the total number of intersections found will be stored in macro` --- could you please tell how to print the output of this macro

Comment: @jsbibra Yes, this is what the macro says, but the macro is a *local* macro, i.e. it is only "known" inside the path. You can print it out by adding `\pgfextra{\typeout{I found \t\space intersections}};` to the path. But this literally prints it it out.

Comment: thank you so much. @Schrödinger'scat You can tell me when they do not have intersection, how to handle errors?

Comment: @JackNguyễn Good point! Added.